# formatear valores en miles en php, javascript para almacenar en las base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo un formulario de precios en html,javascript y php y mi problema es el siguiente. Al agregar valor a los precios el cliente solicito que al cargar el valor, los numeros se dividan mil por puntos, cosa que lo logre. Ahora el problema es al agregar a la base de datos.
ejemplo:

- cargar el monto: 240.000
- y la  base de datos solo almacena 240

¿SOLUCION?

El código es el siguiente:

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="precio" name="precio" type="text"
    onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)"  placeholder="Precio">
 <script>
            function format(input)
            {
                var num = input.value.replace(/\./g, '');
                if (!isNaN(num)) {
                    num = num.toString().split('').reverse().
                       join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
                    num = num.split('').reverse().
                       join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
                    input.value = num;
                } else {
                    alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
                    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '');
                }
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te sugiero utilizar variables diferentes para la vista (presentación en pantalla) y el modelo (registrar en la base de datos). Dale formato a la primera y deja con el 24E+04 a la segunda. ¿Conoces la función `number_format()`? Tal vez te resulte más cómoda

Comment: 1. ¿Qué tipo de dato es el campo en tu base de datos? Si vas a almacenar tres decimales debes usar FLOAT o DECIMAL. Es por eso. Te recomiendo en tu base de datos cambiarlo a DECIMAL(10,3)

Comment: lo tenia de tipo de INT, tenias razon, el problema estaba ahi, en el tipo de dato, por lo que cambien el tipo de dato a varchar, no se si seria lo correcto pero funciona.

Comment: Funciona, pero no es lo correcto. No podrás hacer operaciones (suma, resta,e tc.), incluso se complicaría obtener precios con mayor-que o menor-que. Haz caso a la sugerencia de @FernandoTorres.

Comment: genial. muchas gracias por sus ayudas